# How to make a small drop-down window on the right side of the screen?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

How to make a small drop-down window on the right side of the screen. Which show window for example for 1 second and go back, out of the screen

What method i must use?
or if it can, how make it in interface builder?

Comment: paste your code that you have done so far to achieve this

Comment: i couldn't understand what methods I must use to make so i have project and some window which I made in interface builder.

Comment: you have designed the drop down in interface builder right?

Comment: in interface builder a make only a window which located in right side of screen (without any code)

Comment: what exactly you want.The code for creating drop down and animation for making it disappear? or just how to make make it disappear?

Comment: the code for creating drop down and animation for making it disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for creating drop down refer to [this link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/a-simple-drop-down-list-for-iphone/) and for making it disappear you can use an NSTimer for 1 second

```
NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                               target:self 
                                                             selector:@selector(timerFired:) 
                                                             userInfo:nil 
                                                              repeats:NO];
}


-(void)timerFired:(NSTimer *) theTimer
{ 
    ["your drop down view" removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: for time method thx! but drop down ,  i mean some animation : when the window coming on superview, from outside. p.s. sorry for my english

Comment: sorry im not getting you. are you asking about drop down effect i.e sliding like effect of options. or about placing the drop down window on superview with animation?